# Erro ao executar ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Eu coloquei o que ele pede no web.config.

Web.Config:

```
 <system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="/CustomErrors/401.htm" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/CustomErrors/404.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <remove name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Dá a seguinte mensagem:

```
Report Viewer Configuration Error 
The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add 

<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add 

<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 

to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.
```

Como arrumar isso?

Comment: Tá errado esse `web.config`. A instrução é 1) ou colocar a configuração no `web.config` do projeto a instrução, dentro de `system.web/httpHandlers` **se for IIS 6 ou inferior, ou** 2) colocar a configuração em `system.webServer/handlers` se for IIS 7 ou superior. Não ambas. Vou alterar a resposta pra você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, o erro é bastante claro e te diz exatamente o que fazer. Basicamente, é colocar o seguinte no seu `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      ...
    </httpHandlers>
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

---

**EDIT**

O erro está aqui:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <!-- Retire a declaração abaixo -->
      <!-- remove name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" /-->
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Então @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu coloquei e mesmo assim continua. e agora ?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o `web.config` nela. Pode ser erro na formatação do arquivo.

Comment: Achei o erro quando colei o webconfig aqui .. rs.. Tirei isso <remove name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" /> e funcionou.

Comment: @AndreeH Sim, vou alterar pra ficar certa a resposta.